# Eclipse auto-complete with place-holders?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-jdt

When I invoke a method or constructor and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to select the signature I want, the output I get is shown below. Note that place-holders have been used for the arguments.

[image: place-holders]

Now, if started with a non-argument constructor and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to pick the same signature:

[image: selection]

I get this, note the lack of place-holders:

[image: no place-holders]

Is there any way to trigger Eclipse to put in place-holders in this latter example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm ... yes ... sort of. You can also delete the `()` and then <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> which will get you back to the start.

But I'm not aware of any way to trigger the place holders again (which would often be useful when you already have 2 arguments and want to replace the following ones).

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a great example of another use case. If there is no method, I suppose I should file a feature request with the Eclipse JDT project and see what happens.

Comment: Yes. Please post the URL here, I'm also missing this.